# Position image to left edge of container

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS `Image` component that is rendered inside of a `div`, more specifically, a Material UI `Box` component. I want the image to be positioned to the left edge of the parent container (the Box component). I am having trouble doing this. As you can see in the screenshot, the image centers itself width-wise which throws off the padding of the nav bar? How can I resolve this problem?

```
<Box
    border="1px dashed white"
    position="relative"
    width="250px"
    height="84px"
    display="flex"
    justifyContent="flex-start"
>
    <Image
    fill
    objectFit="contain"
    alt="Black Diasporer logo"
    src="/black_diasporer_logo.png"
    />
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
left:0;
```

to the css.
It will always try to put it as left as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it didn't work. I think this is a tricky issue because it's an image with a transparent background. Since I set the object-fit property to 'contain,' the width just conforms to whatever the height is so that it maintains the original ratio of the image. So technically, the width of the image is filling the whole container, the space that we see on the sides is the transparent part :(

Comment: You could try to modify the object-fit property and then use `left:0;`. I'm not that into next.js